# Start a service at boot time in systemd

Tags: systemd, systemd-boot

I have placed a systemd service file in `usr/lib/systemd/system/testfile.service`.
Here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test service

[Service]
Type=notify

ExecStart=/bin/dd.sh

ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

KillMode=process

Restart=on-failure

RestartSec=30s

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to start the service at boot time these two ways:

1. Created a softlink for the file from `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` to `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` (manually and by using `systemctl enable` command) and rebooted the system; `testfile` service started successfully at boot time.
2. Created a dependency in the existing running service file like `After=testfile.service` and `Wants=testfile.service`, then rebooted the system; `testfile` service started successfully.

But when I place the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system` without using approaches 1 or 2 above, the service is not started. I feel that placing the service file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` is enough for any service to start automatically, without creating the softlinks to wants directory or creating the dependency with the other services.

Please let me know, how do I start a service at boot time which is present in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory without using approaches 1 or 2 above?

I have also created preset files in `usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/` to disable and enable a few services, but it seems like those preset files were not executed: services which I have disabled in the preset file are still enabled after boot up. Please let me know how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should store](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html) your custom unit files in `/etc/systemd/system/`. After you create them, you have to enable them with `systemctl enable name`, which creates necessary symlinks.

Comment: ^ THIS IS CORRECT -- deploy service unit files to `/etc/systemd/system/`, read the manual.

Answer (score 2):

When you place a unit file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` you are merely adding it to the *library* of units available on the system.  But you haven't told the system to run it.

Normally you would then run `systemctl enable myservice`.  This will effectively create the symlink that you did manually.

It's this link that tells the boot processes what units to start up at boot time.

If you're used to older forms of `init` then you can think of this as the equivalent of putting a file into `/etc/init.d`; until you add a link to `/etc/rc3.d/S##myservice` then it won't start at boot time.

Now there may be conditions where other services may depend on your service and that'll cause a start up, but if nothing depends on your service then you have to have the symlink created by `systemctl enable`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried systemctl enable <service> and rebooted the system , service has started at bootime , but my question was to start the service without symlink (systemctl enable or manually creating the symlinks). But it seems like service is not started without any symlinks or dependacny with the other up and running services.