# Manually editing systemd files

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I am new to Linux. I have installed Arch Linux on a new machine.

Yesterday I tried to install GNOME (on top of Xorg). When I enabled `gdm.service` and then rebooted, I was met with a black screen. I think either I messed this up or because my machine has an NVIDIA card.

I have a bootable USB. I realize that I can simply `chroot` into my machine and then just use `systemctl` to disable `gdm.service` BUT I was wondering if I can edit my systemd files to disable it myself and learn a bit about service management in the meantime.

Is this feasible/a good idea? I found the `gdm.service` file in `/lib/systemd/system`. Can I change one of the variables or delete the file altogether to have the same effect? For example, there is a variable in this file, `Restart=always`. If I change this value will I prevent the service from being run during the boot process?

Are there any good resources which explain what is really going on when using `systemctl` commands? I'm guessing that enabled services have a larger footprint then just these files in the `/lib/systemd/system` directory.

[start a service a at bootime in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303297/start-a-service-a-at-bootime-in-systemd) states that `systemctl enable` creates symbolic links to the `/lib/systemd/system` files. Where are these symbolic links and can I edit them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `systemd` <s>disables</s> masks a service, it actually sets a symlink to `/dev/null` instead - see [How to disable a service without using 'systemctl disable'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197670/how-to-disable-a-service-without-using-systemctl-disable)

Additionally, don't edit the files in `/lib/systemd/system/` - instead you make a copy in `/etc/systemd/system/` and then edit *your* copy. That allows the other ones to be owned by your system's package manager, etc. See [RHEL docs for more info](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files). I know you said Arch, but `systemd` is `systemd`.

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron.

Comment: The first paragraph is contradicted by all of the answers that it then points to.

Comment: @JdeBP maybe your problem was that I was using mask and disable interchangeably? I tweaked it.

Comment: Your answer saying wrong things is your problem, not mine.  (-:  Now you aren't even talking about the thing that the question here asks about, or that the Q&A that you point to talk about.